# Game of Keno from Sheldon Ross Chapter 4

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am facing with the following problem:

A game popular in Nevada gambling casinos is Keno, which is played as follows: Twenty numbers are selected at random by the casino from the set of numbers 1 through 80. A player can select from 1 to 15 numbers; a win occurs if some fraction of the player's chosen subset matches any of the 20 numbers drawn by the house. The payoff is a function of the number of elements in the player's selection and the number of matches. For instance, if the player selects only 1 number, then her or she wins if this number is among the set of 20, and the payoff is 2.22 dollar won for every dollar bet/ (As the player's probability of winning in this case is 1/4, it is clear that the "fair" payoff should be 3 dollar won for ever 1 dollar bet.) When the player selects 2 numbers, a payoff (of odds) of $12 won for ever 1 dollar  bet is made when both numbers are among the 20.

(a) What would be the fair payoff in this case?

Let P( subset n ), k denote the probability that exactly k of the n numbers chosen by the player are among the 20 selected by the house.

(b) Compute P( subset n), k

My question is : Why it is the case that : "As the player's probability of winning in this case is 1/4, it is clear that the "fair" payoff should be 3 dollar won for ever 1 dollar bet" ? More specifically, why the probability of winning is 1/4?

Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't get your comment.

Comment: To your question: The expected value is $-1 \$\cdot \frac{3}{4}+3 \$\cdot \frac{1}{4}=0\$ $ ----- $1-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$ is the probability of losing the bet. In general a game is defined as fair, if the expected value is 0.

Comment: I am confused on why the probability of winning is 1/4

Comment: The casino selects 20 numbers out of 80 numbers. The player selects one number out of 80 numbers. The probability, that this number is also selected by the casino is $\frac{20}{80}=\frac{1}{4}$